# Android (WebView) cancel auto-scrolling to image in html

Tags: android, html, webview, scroll, autoscroll

I show following html code in a `WebView`. When I set the html code with `webView.loadData()` the display focused the first image automatically. If I have one or more images, that doesn't matter.
How can I cancel or stop auto-focus / auto-scrolling to image und stay at top of the display ?

I mean, I don't want to disable vertical scrolling, I only want to cancel this behaviour when showing html at first.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<p>Some Text...</p>
<img src="http://..pic1.gif" style="max-width:100%;" /><br><br>
<img src="http://..pic2.gif" style="max-width:100%;" /><br>
<p>Some Text...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure that I understood what you meant, but you could use

```
webView.setInitialScale()
```

to set it's size and

```
pageUp(boolean) or pageDown(boolean)
```

to set it to start/end.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. I had a `ScrollView` as a parent of `WebView`. The `WebView` don't auto-scroll, but my parent `ScrollView` did that.

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer for this question.

Comment: I will do that, but I must wait one day until I can mark this answer as correct.